# Parity Transformations on Molecular Orbitals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, parity

I've been looking into the quantum mechanics of MO Theory and I stumbled across parity symmetries of atomic and molecular wavefunctions.

In short, I understand how the parity operator $\hat{\mathcal{P}}$ acts on single hydrogen-like wavefunctions of atomic orbitals (specifically only the angular part) by a mapping of polar coordinates $\hat{\mathcal{P}}(r, \theta, \phi) \mapsto (r, \pi-\theta, \pi+\phi)$, resulting in:

$$\hat{\mathcal{P}}Y_{\ell}^m(\theta, \phi) = (-1)^{\ell}Y_{\ell}^{m}(\theta, \phi)$$

This would denote s-orbitals to be of even parity and p-orbitals to be odd. However I encounter a problem when I try to repeat the process with molecular orbitals i.e.: through the LCAO method. Taking H$_2$ as an example, with two 1s orbitals interacting with each other, the bonding/antibonding MOs of H$_2$ can be written as:

$$\Psi_{\sigma} = \psi_{1s}(r_1, \theta_1, \phi_1) + \psi_{1s}(r_2, \theta_2, \phi_2)\\
\Psi_{\sigma*} = \psi_{1s}(r_1, \theta_1, \phi_1) - \psi_{1s}(r_2, \theta_2, \phi_2)
$$

When applying $\hat{\mathcal{P}}$ to both of them, I get even (or *gerade*) symmetry for both MOs, which are because both angular parts of the 1s orbitals are even regardless of in-phase/out-of-phase combinations. But it is well-established that the antibonding $\sigma^*$ MO is of *ungerade* symmetry! This also similarly happens with $\sigma$/$\sigma^*$ bonding MOs of p$_z$ orbitals, where both parity operations result in *ungerade* parity even though the bonding MO should be *gerade*.

The question(s) is: Where am I going wrong here? Am I using $\hat{\mathcal{P}}$ incorrectly? Is it appropriate to use it for MOs if it works on AOs? I am aware that there is a separate 'inversion operator' $\hat{\mathbb{i}}$ for centrosymmetric molecules that determines g/u symmetry but I have yet to find any mathematical formulation of this operator (if one exists). And if it does exist, then how does it fit in with LCAO MO wavefunctions?

Comment: Have you considered how the coordinates $r_1$ and $r_2$ are defined?

Comment: The inversion operator is inversion about the center of the molecule, not inversion of each AO around its nucleus (which is what you've done).

Comment: @Buzz Oh that makes sense, I assumed that the operator could just be applied to each orbital and then combined. But is there a mathematical representation of the inversion operator, or is it just down to just doing it by eye?